# Masm32 linker not working

Tags: assembly, linker, masm32

I am trying to learn assembly language, and this is the tutorial I am following: http://www.programminghorizon.com/win32assembly/tut2.html.  I can assemble the code just fine, but when it comes to linking the .obj file, something strange happens.  I typed `ml  /c  /coff  /Cp msgbox.asm` to assemble it, and then `link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS  /LIBPATH:c:\masm32\lib  msgbox.obj`.  When I do this, I just get an infinite scrolling loop of `C:\work\code\ASM>link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS  /LIBPATH:c:\masm32\lib  msgbox.obj`.  When I assembled and linked in the Masm32 editor, it worked fine, but I want to be able to do it from the command line.
This is the code I am trying to assemble/link:

```
.386 
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap:none 
include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
.data 
.code 
start: 
    invoke ExitProcess,0 
end start
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you have a bad link.exe somewhere in your path?  You could try giving a complete path to the link.exe you want to use (make sure it's the same one being used in your editor).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Ok, that worked.  Thanks!  Must have had another link.exe somewhere in my path.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Well, I just came across another problem.  Now when I try to link the .obj file, I get the error `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msgbox.exe'`.  Why would it not be able to open the file?  It hasn't even created it yet!

Comment: The 'open' error probably is coming from the attempt to create the file.  You might experiment with `/out` to specify exactly where link should try to create the file (so it doesn't try to create it in a directory where you don't have write access).  You might also want to examine your TEMP and TMP environment variables.  While you would hope that if they were wrong, you'd get a better message, it's still something to check.